# How to post a photo to facebook using android app?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-4.0

In my android app, I capture a photo from my app camera and i want to post that capture photo to facebook timeline. what is the function to instant post.
I am new for facebook SDK. Any one please help me.Please give the tip step by step.

Comment: http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-share-an-image-on-facebook-in-android/ Hope this give a starting point

Comment: ya its working ,but its only working API key received account. i want to work all account. what can i do.